# JPlayer seekbar not seeking

Tags: javascript, jplayer

We have the jPlayer plugin here on this site http://**********.com the problem is the seek bar is showing the correct position of the track but not allowing the user to change the position of the track.

I have checked the swfpath property and that the JPlayer.swf is in the /js/ folder however its still not working, randomly it has been working in a previous release but unsure whats changed in our software.

Even help in debugging this would be appreciated.

Update: I am using Jquery 1.9.1

---

29-08-2014

I have figured out this is related to my MVC stream function I am using to audit rendering the audio, however now this poses a new question to why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was related to:

Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

The seek function must rely on that to seek forward and back.

Comment: how do i implement this?

Comment: In the code or web service that renders the mp3 binary data